# Able to Click on button but next page not open

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Able to click on Web button but no further page is opening. Manually when I click on the button it uploads the file and next page opens. But through automation, it clicks on the button but nothing happens further.

```java
d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button'][@value='Search']")).click();
```

Comment: provide more info, upload means file upload functionality?

Comment: It seems that you want to upload any file. You must give the address of that file. Provide information/code about How you are giving the address as input?

Comment: d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='fileContainer']//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("D:\\ClassAC_ELV_PWE.xml");

Comment: Please try this.

`d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button'][@value='Search']")).sendK‌​eys("D:\\ClassAC_ELV_PWE.xml");`

Comment: What browser are you using? If it's IE, try setting the RequiresWindowFocus setting to true in the IEDriver.

Comment: Can you post some of the html, to show the button you are clicking on? Are there any javascript events bound to the button?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen focusing issues with Selenium before. My solution was a but ugly, but proved to be very reliable. I scripted a clicking on something I knew was there but has no click action before going to my real click action. In you case it would be:

```
d.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).click();
d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='button'][@value='Search']")).click();
```